# How to use System(const char*) in TC++

Tags: c

Today , When i coding, met a question..my Code as follow:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    system("dir");
    getch();
}
```

The question : The user Screen is nothing..Why ?  where is my result?

Comment: Please specify the full path to `dir` (in this case its probably `/bin/dir`) - assuming relative paths will work correctly is a common security vulnerability. Even if it doesn't matter for this program, you don't want to be in the habit when it does :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output when using `system`, at least into something you can read in your application, you need to pipe the output:

```
system("dir > /tmp/output.txt");
FILE *f  = fopen("/tmp/output.txt", "r");

char text[1024]; // max sizeof of 1 kb, any more and I'd consider using `malloc()` instead.

fread(text, 1, 1024, f);

printf("%s\n", text);

fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping , If i want to print it to Screen, how can i do ?

Comment: @Tu_JianWu `printf()` is your friend :)

Comment: Ah.. no, uh.. is there a way didn't need save the result to a file firstly ? i.e print result to Screen directly..

Comment: So your suggestion is to direct the output to a temporary file, then read the contents of that file and print to stdout.  How is that helpful?  `system("dir")` should invoke the `dir` command and send its output to stdout.  If it's not working, your changes aren't going to help.

Comment: Oh, and the OP is on Windows, or possibly MS-DOS; there probably isn't a `/tmp` directory.

Comment: I' m so sorry..I make a mistake.. my compiler is turbo c++  , not turbo c..it will work on turbo c, but not for turbo c++...Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your program, at least one of which has already been mentioned.

`void main()` should be `int main(void)`.

As I recall, the Windows/DOS `getch` function is declared in `<conio.h>`; you should have a `#include` directive for it.  Be aware that both `<conio.h>` and `getch` are non-standard.

Since `main` returns `int`, you should return an `int` result.

But none of these problems explain the problem you're seeing.

With these changes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("dir");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This *should* work; it should show a directory listing of whatever directory your program runs in (which is determined by TC; I don't know the details).

It's possible that the program is running in an empty directory, which means the `dir` command wouldn't show any files, but it should still produce some output.

Try commenting out the `system()` call and adding a `printf` call (note the added `#include <stdio.h>`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This should open a console window, print `"Hello, world"` in it, and wait for you to type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you still don't see any output (either no console window, or a console window with nothing in it), then you have a problem that's not related to the `system()` call.  Most likely the problem has to do with the way you're using Turbo C (I presume that's what "TC" stands for).

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake.. my compiler is Turbo c++ , it doesn't work.. it will work on Turbo C.. Why ?

Comment: @Tu_JianWu: I don't know.  How exactly does it not work?  When you use Turbo C, you should get a new console window with the program's output.  With Turbo C++, do you get a console window or not?  If you do, is there *any* output in it, and does it close when you type Enter?

Comment: yes, i get .But there is noting on screen. when i type Enter, it will close also..

Comment: @Tu_JianWu: With the "Hello, world" program in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function in every C program is supposed to return an `int` you are returning `void`

Change `void` to `int`:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("dir");
    getch();
}
```

When I tested, the `dir` command ran in my console and printed to standard out.

Comment: @Tu_JianWu Did you try running the program again? when I run this I receive the output of the `dir` command written to standard out in my console.

Comment: yeah! i updated it.. Maybe my environment(TC2.0) is different from you.

Comment: Certainly `main` should return `int` (and it should be `int main(void)` rather than `int main()`), but that's unlikely to be related to the described symptoms.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well let me put it this way, I ran the OP's code on my machine with their original function definition `void main()` and no output was generated. I changed the definition to `int main()` and ran the program again, this time the `dir` command generated output to STDOUT. I don't think that this should be specific to my machine, please try it and let me know if you don't receive output. I am using gcc 4.5.2

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: You're using gcc?  On what system?  If you're on a Unix-like system, then `getch()` is a completely different function than the one the OP is using.

Comment: @KeithThompson I am running Cygwin on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: So am I.  I get "undefined reference to `_getch'".  When I comment out the `getch()` call, it works even with the incorrect `void main()` (though the `dir` command it invokes is not the Windows one).

Comment: @KeithThompson I am unsure of why I'm not receiving the same error. What is the target when you type `gcc -v`, mine is mingw32

Comment: I' m so sorry..I make a mistake.. my compiler is turbo c++  , not turbo c..it will work on turbo c, but not for turbo c++...Thanks again.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: `Target: i686-pc-cygwin` (it's the gcc included with Cygwin, not MinGW).

Comment: @KeithThompson Pretty sure I changed the configuration so I could compile a bunch of languages with the minGW compiler, it has been so long since I set it up that I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

May be he is the running the program directly in the  Turbo C IDE and hence his output is not visible. If he runs the program directly from cmd line it works. I remember you need to run Alt - F5 or some other combination to see the output window in Turbo C++